# Rellenar vacío con el dato anterior

Tags: r, rstudio

Quiero hacer algo bastante simple pero no puedo recordar cuál es el comando que me permite pegar en una celda vacía el valor encima dentro de una misma columna. Es decir, quiero rellenar los vacíos con el valor inmediatamente anterior.
Si alguien lo recuerda se lo agradeceré!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado. Era la función [fill](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html).
Moraleja: googleen en inglés.